# I Need to connect my java application to accses database in windows 7 x64?

Tags: java, sql, windows-7, database-connection, ms-access-2007

```
try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\\DataBase1.mdb","","");
     int id=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter ID"));
     String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name");
     String Phone=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter PHone");
String mobile=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Moblie");
//String sql="insert  into friends values "id,'"+home
     Statement ss=conn.createStatement();
       ss.executeUpdate("insert into friends values("+id+",'"+name+"','"+Phone+"','"+mobile+"')");
        Statement s=conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet res=s.executeQuery("select*from friends order by id");
        while(res.next()){
            System.out.println(res.getString(1)+"\t"+res.getString(2)+"\t"+res.getString(3)+"\t"+res.getString(4));

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }

    }
```

this is my code but when i run it 
this exception show ("java.sql.SQLException: ??[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] ???? ??? ???")
idont know what is the problem pleas help???

Comment: Which line does the exception occur on?

Comment: in this line:Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\\DataBase1.mdb","","");

Answer (score 2):

What about using PreparedStatement instead of Statement? I think your code is not accepting hardcoded Variables! And, to stop getting into more trouble, keep in mind to close the connection.

Also you need spaces around the star `"select * from friends order by id"`